# Does NSubstitute support the idea of Partial Mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

Does NSubstitute support the idea of Partial Mocks?

http://nsubstitute.github.com/

http://www.ayende.com/wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks.ashx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! This feature was introduced in version 1.7.0 (released January 2014).

http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/

Answer (score 4):

*Update:* As @Brian points out, NSubstitute 1.7+ [supports partial mocks](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/partial-subs/)

*Original answer:*

Not as of v1.0.

It is something we're considering for vNext. If you have specific syntax ideas or requirements please post to the [user group](http://groups.google.com/group/nsubstitute). I've added an [issue for this to the issue log](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/issue/41), so you could also add details there.

Comment: u may also want to change/close this answer. since it is highest voted but actually now incorrect

Comment: Done. Not sure on the etiquette for major updates to answers, so hope this is ok.

Answer (score -3):

I am using version 1.3.0.0, but I could do:

```
Constraint failing = Substitute.For<Constraint>();
failing.Matches(-1).Returns(false);
```

Where Constraint is a class with virtual methods and the method call was substituted just fine.

Comment: but u cant pick and choose which methods to mock