# Does FakeItEasy support the idea of Partial Mocks?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, fakeiteasy

Similar to [this question about NSubstitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600825/does-nsubstitute-support-the-idea-of-partial-mocks), I want to know if one is able to implement partial mocks using the [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy/wiki) library.

FakeItEasy seems to have an overall nicer syntax than moq (like the strongly-typed way the former deals with passing parameters to a constructor of a faked class). I'm thinking about switching to FakeItEasy, but I really need partial mock support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes](http://code.google.com/p/fakeiteasy/issues/detail?id=26). Syntax is no different than regular fake:

```
var fake = A.Fake<Fake>();
A.CallTo(() => fake.SomeMethod()).CallBaseMethod();
```

Or, to override all calls with base calls:

```
var fake = A.Fake<Fake>();
A.CallTo(fake).CallBaseMethod();
```

**Edit** Just to make clear: the fake object must be created over a *concrete* class.

Comment: I needed to use var fake = A.Fake<Fake>(); (the concrete object instead of the interface) and make SomeMethod virtual before I got it working (v 1.8.0).

Comment: @Aligned: you're right, the fake object must be created over the concrete class. I'll edit jimmy_keen's answer in order to make that clear.